# How can I enable / disable Angular date picker for a specific date using Angular Material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a requirement to show the dates for start date and end date i.e., if the start date is `dd/mm/yyyy` format `10/09/2020` and end date should be till yesterday i.e., `09/09/2020` and all the remaining dates should be disabled.

How can I achieve this?

```
 <mat-form-field color="accent" appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1"  [max]="tomorrow" [formControl]="startDate">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field color="accent" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" [min]="today" max="tomorrow" [formControl]="endDate">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You can also, if only want a min and max value, use  `[min]` and `[max]` property: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepickerInput

Comment: @Eliseo, i tried the same                                                                                                   @Input() min: any;
  @Input() max: any;
  tomorrow = new Date();
  future = new Date();                                                                                                            this.tomorrow.setDate(this.tomorrow.getDate());
    this.future.setDate(this.future.getDate());

Comment: Sorry, I've explained it very bad, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter validation.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Datepicker with filter validation */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-filter-example.html',
})
export class DatepickerFilterExample {
  myFilter = (d: Date | null): boolean => {
    const day = (d || new Date()).getDay();
    // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }
}
```

Example from the offical docs  [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples)

Answer (score 0):

May I want to say. In .ts

```
today=new Date();
tomorrow=new Date(this.today.getTime()+24*60*60*1000);
```

in .html

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="today" [max]="tomorrow">
```

Comment: i have added the HTML part of what i tried but it's still not working..

Comment: remember that mat-date-picker works with javascript Date object. Just put the answer in a stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt1cdq?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html. Check if your error is in another place